# What's the difference between `mkdir -p` and `install -d`?

Tags: c, coreutils

What is the difference in what is being performed by `mkdir -p` and `install -d`, in terms of what changes the two commands are doing to the system?

Comment: `install -d` might not be POSIX, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: At least in `busybox` by comparing [mkdir.c](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/mkdir.c) and [install.c](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/install.c) you see that there is some difference when it comes to handling file modes, in latter (`install`) the folders are apparently first created with a hardcoded file mode of `0755` and only later set to a different value. (Some sort of workaround for certain GNU coreutils versions? Can someone more knoledgable please explain?) Also in latter the user and group ID can be specifically set. I ignored SELINUX.

Comment: Does it trouble you that there might be more than one way of doing the same thing in UNIX/Linux?

Comment: @mdpc, No, I just want to learn the difference, if any. Do they really do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference between `mkdir -p` and `install -d` is that if the directory already exists, **only `install -d` will try to set the ownership and file mode bits**.

- `install -d` will call `make_dir_parents` with `preserve_existing` set to `false`
- `mkdir -p` will call `make_dir_parents` with `preserve_existing` set to `true`.

If `preserve_existing` is `true` and the directory already exists, the function will not attempt to set the ownership and file mode bits.

`mkdir -p` and `install -d` in coreutils call the exact same `make_dir_parents` function.

Coreutil sources:

- [`mkdir.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/2ed7c2867974ccf7abc61c34ad7bf9565489c18e/src/mkdir.c#L165)
- [`install.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/2ed7c2867974ccf7abc61c34ad7bf9565489c18e/src/install.c#L447)

Answer (score 7):

For starters, `mkdir -p` is POSIX, `install` is not. Then, we have this from [the GNU `install` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html):

> If the `--directory` (`-d`) option is given, `install` creates each
>   *directory* and any missing parent directories. Parent directories are created with mode ‘`u=rwx,go=rx`’ (755), regardless of the `-m` option
>   or the current umask. See [Directory Setuid and Setgid](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html#Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid), for how
>   the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of parent directories are
>   inherited.

And:

> ‘`-d`’
>   ‘`--directory`’
>   Create any missing parent directories, giving them the default
>   attributes. Then create each given directory, setting their owner,
>   group and mode as given on the command line or to the defaults.

So:

1. For GNU `install`, the permissions of the parent directories could be different.
2. `install` lets you set the ownership of the leaf directory.