# How create many nested directories and defining the permission to all them in one command?

Tags: permissions, directory, mkdir

In Linux the following two commands work as expected:

```
mkdir -m 555 new_directory
mkdir -p a/b/c
```

But the following does not work *as expected*:

```
mkdir -m 555 -p a/b/c
```

the 3 directories are created but only the latest recieves the `555` permission. The `a` and `b` directories have the default permissions.

So how accomplish the goal described in the title? Is it possible?

BTW - I selected `555` how a random case, it fails with `666` and `777` too

Comment: It's not possible with `mkdir`

Comment: interesting, it doesn't even obey the `umask` setting for the intermediates, but forces `umask` to `022`. I do wonder if that counts as a bug though...

Comment: @ilkkachu It would be either a bug or perhaps a security reason to avoid a potential problem or risk of access

Comment: @ilkkachu huh, for me (zsh, GNU coreutils 8.32) it does respect the `umask`, but `555` is not *settable* per umask, it's *preventable*, at best.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, you'd need to set the umask to 0222. But there's the thing, the directory wouldn't have write permission, so it couldn't create the next one. So any tool doing that would have to create the directories first, and then go back to remove the write access from the owner.

Comment: BTW I selected `555` how a random number how example in this question, it could be other value such as  `770`

Comment: @ManuelJordan uff! Important info that comes too late! **EDIT** your question to include this!

Comment: for that, umask does work

Comment: @ilkkachu done - Does `umask` "fail" just with `555`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, it because I tried with many combinations and all scenarios I had the same undesired behavior

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between `mkdir -p` and `install -d`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340169/whats-the-difference-between-mkdir-p-and-install-d)

Comment: @ManuelJordan thanks for making the edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expressly list the directories, parent first, you can achieve your stated aim of creating the directories in one command:

```
mkdir -m 555 -p a a/b a/b/c
```

With shells with support for csh-style brace expansion such as `bash` you can simplify this a little at the expense of readability:

```
mkdir -m 555 -p a{,/b{,/c}}
```

Notice, however, that **for permissions `555` both commands will fail** if it actually needs to create any of the parent directories: such directories are created with permissions that do not allow writing, and therefore next level directories cannot be created.

Finally, a `bash` shell script that will also give you the functionality to create the multiple directories in one command as requested, by wrapping the complexity in a function. This one will attempt to apply the permissions to newly created directories from the bottom up, so it will be possible to end up with directories that have no write permission:

```
mkdirs()
{
    local dirs=() modes=() dir old

    # Grab arguments
    [[ "$1" == '-m' ]] && modes=('-m' "$2") && shift 2
    dir=$1

    # Identify missing directories
    while [[ "$dir" != "$old" ]]
    do
        [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && dirs+=("$dir")
        old="$dir"
        dir="${dir%/*}"
    done

    # Create necessary directories and maybe fix up permissions
    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
    do
        mkdir -p "${modes[@]}" "$dir" || return 1
        [[ -n "${modes[1]}" ]] && chmod "${modes[1]}" "$dir"
    done
}
```

Example

```
mkdirs -m 555 a/b/c

ls -ld a a/b a/b/c
dr-xr-xr-x+ 1 roaima roaima 0 Jan  7 10:01 a
dr-xr-xr-x+ 1 roaima roaima 0 Jan  7 10:01 a/b
dr-xr-xr-x+ 1 roaima roaima 0 Jan  7 10:01 a/b/c
```

As always, this function can be put standalone into an executable script that's somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdirs()
{
    ...as above...
}

mkdirs "$@"
```

Comment: if I try `mkdir -m 555 -p r{,/s{,/t}}` I receive twice: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘r/s’: Permission denied`

Comment: Yes of course you will. Please read the last paragraph of my answer

Comment: Sorry, tired so far, I didn't read well that part - both commands work, but seems mandatory apply the verbose approach about repeat the names. It for complex/long paths would be something 'ugly' for scripts purposes. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: huge thanks for the extra code. Valuable your feedback for all the community.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your first paragraph, but `mkdir -m 555 -p a a/b a/b/c` fails under `bash` on two BSD variants I tested (FreeBSD and Mac OSX).  FreeBSD reports: `mkdir: a/b: Permission denied\nmkdir: a/b: Permission denied` while Mac OSX reports: `mkdir: a/b: Permission denied\nmkdir: a/b/c: Permission denied`

Comment: Actually, it fails under Ubuntu as well, so it may well be that I am misunderstanding your solution.  It does work on any of the platforms as `root`, perhaps because `root` can override the lack of write access. Thanks for your note re: writability, fixed: `ls -ld .` `drwxrwxr-x 3 username root 4096 Jan 10 13:55 .` That takes away the top-level permission denied on `./a`. Remaining errors as before: `
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a/b’: Permission denied\nmkdir: cannot create directory ‘a/b’: Permission denied`

Comment: @JimL. I've just realised what you're trying to do. The first command will indeed fail (please read the paragraph starting "Notice...". I included it because it mimicked the command that the OP was trying to use. I've emphasised this warning as part of the explanation

Answer (score 2):

It does look like `mkdir` doesn't apply the mode set by `-m` when it creates the intermediary directories. But, at least in most cases, you can use the `umask` to modify the permissions it sets for them.

The `umask` works by *clearing* the permission bits that are *set* in the umask, so if you want the intermediaries to have e.g. the permissions `0700`, set umask to `0077`. Using a subshell here to contain the umask change:

```
$ ( umask 0077; mkdir -p a/b )
$ ls -ld a
drwx------ 3 ilkkachu ilkkachu 4096 Jan  7 07:23 a/
$ ls -ld a/b
drwx------ 2 ilkkachu ilkkachu 4096 Jan  7 07:23 a/b/
```

Similarly, to get the permissions `0555`, you'd set umask to `0222`. But this doesn't actually work for the intermediaries, they are created with permissions `0755` instead. That is, the write permission for the owning user is added.

[POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) for the permissions of the intermediate pathname components (see under the `-p` option):

> [...] the
> `mkdir`
> utility shall create any pathname components of the path prefix of dir that do not name an existing directory [by equivalent of creating the missing directory]
> and then calling the `chmod()` function with the following arguments: [...]
>
> 2. **The value `(S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR|~filemask)&0777` as the mode argument, where `filemask` is the file mode creation mask of the process.**

<sub>(`S_IWUSR` and `S_IXUSR` are the C constants for those permissions bits.)</sub>

The [GNU coreutils online manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mkdir-invocation.html):

> `-p`, `--parents`
> Make any missing parent directories for each argument, setting their file permission bits to `=rwx,u+wx`, that is, with the umask modified by `u+wx`. Ignore existing parent directories, and do not change their file permission bits.

It goes on to say that the `-m` option doesn't apply to these, but that you can hence use the umask to control the permissions of them.

<sub>(Though the text there looks off, it mentions "The umask must include `u=wx` for this method to work", which seems to be missing the inverted sense of the umask.)</sub>

---

Presumably `mkdir` does that because otherwise it wouldn't be able to create the next directory inside the one just created without write permissions. The same happens for the access / search (`x`) permission bit, for the same reason.

So, if you want to create directories you can't write to or search yourself, it looks like you'll just have to `chmod` them after. Otherwise, setting `umask` for the `mkdir` works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `install` command (not standard, from BSD in the 80s also included in GNU coreutils) as:

```
install -m 555 -d a/b/c a/b a
```

Or with shells with support for `csh`-style brace expansion:

```
install -m 555 -d a{/b{/c,},}
```

Note that if the directory components already existed beforehand, their permissions (the permissions of the directories they point to for symlinks) will be *changed* to 0555.

To only change the permissions of directory components that are being newly created, you could do it as a function. For instance, in `zsh`:

```
mkdirhierperm() {
  local mode=$1 dir=$2 dirs=()
  until [[ -d $dir ]] dirs[1,0]=$dir dir=$dir:h
  if (( $#dirs == 0 )); then
    (umask 77 && mkdir -p -- $dirs[-1]) &&
      chmod -- $mode $dirs
  fi
}

mkdirhierperm 555 a/b/c
mkdirhierperm 555 /full/path/to/some/new/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

One might do this in 2 steps: first call `mkdir` to create the directories and then run `find . -type d -exec chmod 555 {} \;` to modify the modes.